# Populate a Timeline webpart from another webpart on the same page

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-search-web-part, timeline

The description of the timeline webpart is as follows:
"Use this timeline to show a high level view of data from another webpart or tasks list."

I read this as meaning I can populate a timeline with another webpart's data, not just a static task list.
I have a content search web part that is pulling in tasks from across my site collection based on certain criteria, is it possible to display the tasks from this content search webpart on my timeline? Or have I just misinterpreted the capability of the webpart from the wording?

Answer (score 0):

The timeline is a graphical way to display a task list.

It is impossible to display the tasks from this content search web parts on OOB Timeline web part.

As a workaround to achieve that, you need to deploy customizations.

[Plan customizations, solutions, and apps for SharePoint Online.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Plan-customizations-solutions-and-apps-for-SharePoint-Online-b7898ebf-69b7-4196-81e3-b04e1a4e7d67)

Comment: thank you, it's misleading the wording that has been used to describe the web part. Would you have any idea which sort of customisation might best suit this scenario if I was to still try and get this functionality to work?